# Appcelerator Ti.map selected annotation image

Tags: android, ios, maps, titanium, appcelerator

I'm working with the ti.map module on Appcelerator and cant seem to find any solution to change the image of the annotation once selected. How can this be done?

Need support for iOS and Android
Using Titanium SDK 7.2

Comment: can you show us the code you've used to try it?

Comment: I dont really have any code because I'm not sure how to do it. There is no selected annotation image property I can set. 

Right now what I am doing is removing the annotation and adding a new one with a different image. Then when they select something else, I have do re-drop the old one, remove the new selected annotation and ... very complicated. Not sure what the correct was of doing this is?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom view as annotation:

```
var myAnnotationView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage: '/my_image.png',
});

var customAnnotation = map.createAnnotation({
   customView: myAnnotationView,
   latitude: lat,
   longitude: lon,
   title: 'My custom pin'
});

myAnnotationView.backgroundImage = '/my_image2.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom View :

```
var _costumView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage: '/image1.png' }); 

var _annotation = map.createAnnotation({
   customView: _costumView,
   latitude: _latitude,
   longitude: _longitude
});

_costumView.backgroundImage = '/image2.png';
_annotation.customView = _costumView;
```